# oauth 2.0 any way to have permanent consent?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to create an application that uses Microsoft Graph and the OAuth 2.0 authentication. I have to give consent whenever I start up my application.

Is there any way to permanently give the app consent from a user?

Comment: Yes. You can write a token cache helper class that reads and writes from it. If no one helps look I will look for my code later. They have articles on it too.

Comment: But do i have to renew the cache at some point? my end goal is to use the application as a background service.

Comment: Yes. You have access and refresh tokens. The refresh token lasts a long time and it used to get a new access token.

Comment: I assume that this requires user interaction, similar to consenting in the first place?

Comment: No. It is a cache. You store the results of the consent screen. That is it. Then they are not asked any more.

Comment: Okay, ill take a look at using a refresh token to stay connected. Thank you

Comment: The refresh token will also expire at some point. If you need "forever" access from an application that doesn't support user interaction, OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds) which authenticates your application and not the user.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, there are two options here:

1. If you request the scope `offline_access` you will receive a `refresh_token` along with your `access_token`. When your `access_token` expires, the `refresh_token` can be submitted to the `/token` endpoint for a new set.

   I wrote up a primer on the v2 Endpoint that covers how to use [Refresh Tokens](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/#refreshing-a-token) that you might find helpful for this.
2. Use the `client_credentials` OAuth grant. This grant is specifically intended for service-to-service/daemon scenarios. They work a little differently in that they use Application scopes as opposed to Delegated and there isn't a user in context (so calls to `/me` need to be replaced with `/users/{id}` instead).

   Client Credentials also *always* requires Admin Consent. Since there isn't a specific user being authenticated, it requires an Admin authorize your application up front. Once this happens, your application will remain authorized (unless expressly blocked by an Admin).

   You can find details on how this process works under [Get access without a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service)

Comment: Refresh tokens can expire though for various reasons so you should not expect it to work always. In those cases you would need the user to re-authenticate.

Comment: Excellent point, I should have mentioned this explicitly. This is one of the reasons I'd recommend going with Client Credentials. Unless your app is occasionally used interactively you will almost assuredly run into the service failing without a clear way to resolve the problem.

Comment: One bad side of Client Credentials is org-wide access though. We use the delegated access + refresh token approach in one of our apps so that the permissions we require on the customer tenant are minimal.

Comment: It generally comes down to how mission-critical the service is. If it is something that can go down for a period of time without hair catching on fire, then I typically recommend refresh tokens and have the service email an admin if they need to re-authorize. For mission-critical services, it is better to go through the Client Credentials process and avoid the potential downtime.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a class defined like this:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.
// All rights reserved.
//
// This code is licensed under the MIT License.
//
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
// of this software and associated documentation files(the "Software"), to deal
// in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
// to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and / or sell
// copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
// furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions :
//
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
// all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
// AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
// LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
// OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
// THE SOFTWARE.
//
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

namespace OutlookCalIFConsole
{
    static class TokenCacheHelper
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the user token cache
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static TokenCache GetUserCache()
        {
            if (usertokenCache == null)
            {
                usertokenCache = new TokenCache();
                usertokenCache.SetBeforeAccess(BeforeAccessNotification);
                usertokenCache.SetAfterAccess(AfterAccessNotification);
            }
            return usertokenCache;
        }

        static TokenCache usertokenCache;

        /// <summary>
        /// Path to the token cache
        /// </summary>
        public static string CacheFilePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + "msalcache.txt";

        private static readonly object FileLock = new object();

        public static void BeforeAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            lock (FileLock)
            {
                args.TokenCache.Deserialize(File.Exists(CacheFilePath)
                    ? File.ReadAllBytes(CacheFilePath)
                    : null);
            }
        }

        public static void AfterAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            // if the access operation resulted in a cache update
            if (args.TokenCache.HasStateChanged)
            {
                lock (FileLock)
                {
                    // reflect changesgs in the persistent store
                    File.WriteAllBytes(CacheFilePath, args.TokenCache.Serialize());
                    // once the write operationtakes place restore the HasStateChanged bit to filse
                    args.TokenCache.HasStateChanged = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your main class constructor you do something like:

```
TokenCacheHelper.CacheFilePath = Program.Options.TokenCachePath;
PublicClientApp = new PublicClientApplication(_AppID, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common", TokenCacheHelper.GetUserCache());
```

Then you should be able to use your normal credential code. The above class is taken from here:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-desktop/blob/master/active-directory-b2c-wpf/TokenCacheHelper.cs

And there is a full discussion about the mechanics [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/467) (see the discussion thread).

Something like:

```
   public bool InitAuthenticatedClientAsync()
    {
        string appID = "~~~";
        PublicClientApplication PublicClientApp = new PublicClientApplication(appID, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common", TokenCacheHelper.GetUserCache());
        string[] _scopes = new string[] { "user.read", "calendars.readwrite" };
        bool bSuccess = true;

        _graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
            new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                async (requestMessage) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        _AuthResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(_scopes, PublicClientApp.Users.FirstOrDefault());
                    }
                    catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
                    {
                        // A MsalUiRequiredException happened on AcquireTokenSilentAsync. This indicates you need to call AcquireTokenAsync to acquire a token
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

                        try
                        {
                            _AuthResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(_scopes);
                        }
                        catch (MsalException msalex)
                        {
                            SimpleLog.Log(msalex);
                            Console.WriteLine("GetAuthenticatedClientAsync: Acquire token error. See log.");
                            bSuccess = false;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        SimpleLog.Log(ex);
                        Console.WriteLine("GetAuthenticatedClientAsync: Acquire token silently error. See log.");
                        bSuccess = false;
                    }

                    if(bSuccess)
                    {
                        // Append the access token to the request.
                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", _AuthResult.AccessToken);

                        // Get event times in the current time zone.
                        requestMessage.Headers.Add("Prefer", "outlook.timezone=\"" + TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id + "\"");
                    }
                }));

        return bSuccess;
    }
```

Hope this helps.